# How to push in array?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do cart by angular2(TS)

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';    
import {Cart} from './product'; //interface id: Number; name: String

 @Injectable()
 export class ProductService {
 public products;
 public cart : Cart[] = [];

    addToCart(products: Object) {
      console.log('product=',products)
      this.cart.push(this.products);
      console.log('cart=',this.cart);
           }
```

When I push products in method I get

```
product= Object {id: 13, name: "Bombasto"}
```

but in

```
console.log('cart=',this.cart);
```

I have "undefined". Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that there is a typo in your code:

```
addToCart(products: Object) {
  console.log('product=',products)
  this.cart.push(products); // <--------
  console.log('cart=',this.cart);
}
```

If you want to use the `products` parameter, you should remove the `this` keyword when using it at the level of the `push` method.

With the `this` keyword, you use the `products` property of the `ProductService` class which is undefined. So you try to use an undefined value in the array... That's why you see the undefined in your trace.

Comment: Yeahhhh)))  git commit -m "Cart" ))) Thanks. I'll mark an answer in 4 minutes